# Retrieving mysql data using ajax and then manipulating it

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My question has part solutions on this site but not a complete answer.

On my wordpress homepage I display a counter of the number of questions answered within our webapp. This is displayed using jQuery and AJAX to retrieve the question count from a php file and works fine with this code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
function load() {
jQuery.get('/question_count.php', function(data) {jQuery('#p1').html( data );  });
}
load();
setInterval(load,10000);
});
```

Is there a way to display counting up to the new number retrieved rather than just immediately displaying it?

Comment: Using this method, as you've outlined, will actually hinder your website. Because the `load()` event will actually consume an `HTTPD` thread, you're going to be bottlenecking the browser. I suppose it's fine as long as you don't have other events that require server interaction, but if you do, you're going to see a decreases in performance. This is why we leverage a technique such as Long Polling / Comet Polling, or perhaps even using something like `node.js`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
function countTo(n) {
    var p = $("#p1"),
        c = parseInt(p.html(), 10) || 0,
        dir = (c > n ? -1 : 1);    // count up or down?

    if (c != n) {
        p.html((c + dir) + "");

        setTimeout(function() {
            countTo(n);
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

Call it in your success handler

```
jQuery.get('/question_count.php', function(data) {
    var n = parseInt(data, 10);

    countTo(n);
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vqkDv/)

Comment: This was my initial idea as well, but I wondered if there is a limit to recursive call depth in JavaScript.

Comment: ohhh *smack self in head* async calls, you got me again

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a setInterval event so that the count up is visable to human eyes.
This may be a problem if you eventually reach enough questions where the count takes a long time to reach the end.

Code will look like this:

```
function load(){
   jQuery.get('/question_count.php', function(data){
      var curr = 0;
      var max = parseInt(data);
      var interval = setInterval(function(){
        if(curr==max){
           clearInterval(interval);
        }
        jQuery('#p1').html( curr );
        curr+=1; //<-- if the number of questions gets very large, increase this number
      },
      10 //<-- modify this to change how fast it updates
      });
   }
}
```